# Reg Replace text block first occurrence + last occurrence

Tags: java, regex

Just a little question.

I have to quote a text inside a couple of string taking the first occurrence of one and the last occurrence of other.

Ex.

```
[quote]
Hi to all
[quote]
im fine
[/quote]
[/quote]
```

I hate to inscribe all the quoted text inside a DIV. So I have a regexp like:

```
String pattern = "\\[quote\\](.*?)\\[\\\quote\\\]";
body = body.replaceAll(pattern, "<div class=\"quote\">[quote]$1[/quote]</div>");
```

It works but the regexp take from first [quote] to first [/quote] leaving the second [/quote] outside the DIV. What I want obtain is:

```
<div class="quote">
[quote]
Hi to all
[quote]
im fine
[/quote]
[/quote]
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make it greedy by removing `?` in `.*?`?

Comment: Unless you clarify your question by adding more test cases + expected output, it may not be possible to give you a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Replace [] with <> and use an xml parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like, as @nhahtdh says, you simply want to remove the `?` to make the `*` greedy.

Compare:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String    input = "[quote]\n"
        + "Hi to all\n"  
        + "[quote]\n"
        + "im fine\n"
        + "[/quote]\n"
        + "[/quote]\n";

    System.out.println( input.replaceAll( "(?s)\\[quote\\](.*?)\\[/quote]", "<div class=\"quote\">\n[quote]$1[/quote]\n</div>" ));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println( input.replaceAll( "(?s)\\[quote\\](.*)\\[/quote]", "<div class=\"quote\">\n[quote]$1[/quote]\n</div>" ));
  }
```

output:

```
<div class="quote">
[quote]
Hi to all
[quote]
im fine
[/quote]
</div>
[/quote]


<div class="quote">
[quote]
Hi to all
[quote]
im fine
[/quote]
[/quote]
</div>
```